# Robotium testing failed because of deleteDatabase()

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, robotium

I've refactored my application to use a ContentProvider and all the CursorLoader framework but since I've done it, all my test failed because of database error like

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed.

but these occure only in robotium test mode. When I test manually the app it seems to work.

2 days that I'm trying to makes my tests working…

The database management code is available here : 
http://code.google.com/p/radis/source/browse/#hg%2Fsrc%2Ffr%2Fgeobert%2Fradis%2Fdb

My test code is available here : 
http://code.google.com/p/radis/source/browse/?repo=robotium#hg%2Fsrc%2Ffr%2Fgeobert%2Fradis%2Frobotium

Thanks for any help, this is driving me nuts…

Comment: Did you get this to work? If not can you post a stacktrace? is the error always in the same place?

Comment: I've workedaround the problem by setting a static var to tell the app it is in testing mode and delete the database from the app if the var is true, check http://code.google.com/p/radis/source/browse/src/fr/geobert/radis/robotium/AccountListTest.java?repo=robotium and http://code.google.com/p/radis/source/browse/src/fr/geobert/radis/AccountList.java (search for ROBOTIUM_MODE)