# Google Espresso: delete user data on each test

Tags: android, android-espresso, kotlin

I'm looking for a way to delete the database from the app before each test using Google Espresso.

I've got this piece of code in a @Before function (kotlin code):

```
@Before
fun setUp() {
    val appCtx = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().applicationContext
    DBPrefsManager.getInstance(appCtx).resetAll()
    val client = appCtx.contentResolver.acquireContentProviderClient("fr.geobert.radis.db")
    val provider = client.localContentProvider as DbContentProvider
    provider.deleteDatabase(appCtx)
    client.release()

    val i = Intent()
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
    activityRule.launchActivity(i)
}
```

It used to work before but I left my part time project for some month and now, after upgrading to API 23 and new testing framework version, all my test can't start because of the "activityRule.launchActivity(i)". So I got rid of the last 3 lines and the tests can start again but by delete database code fails one time in two :(

Is there any better way to delete user data before the app is started by the test framework?

Comment: Can you define "code fails" ... an exception, error message, doesn't do anything, etc.

Comment: That was by biggest issue: no error whatsoever, just the data being still there. I've workaround this by doing the same stick I've done before with Robotium https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125656/robotium-testing-failed-because-of-deletedatabase#comment19606825_12125656

Comment: is a problem so;lved?

Comment: As I said in the comment juste above yours, I've used a workaround